# Finding mean and variance with only probabilities $x>n$ and $x>m$

Tags: probability, variance, density-function, means

A normally distributed random variable $x$ is known to satisfy $P(x>58)=0.24$ and $P(x>24)=0.87$.
Determine the mean and variance which describe the distribution of $x$.

So I'm familiar with finding the variance and mean of probability density functions when I have an actual function to work with, but now that I'm working with just probabilities, all I've really been able to do with this is find the probability that $(x<24)=0.13$, probability $(24<x<58)=0.63$ and $P(x>58)$.

Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction, as I can't find a similar question in my lectures/course notes or online, they all seem to be done with functions.

Comment: You'll need a [normal table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_normal_table) to solve this question. Specifically, the table will tell you what values $a$ and $b$ satisfy $P(Z>a) =0.24$ and $P(Z>b)=0.87$ for a standard normal $Z$. Then note that $(x-\mu)/\sigma$ is standard normal, and you can then solve for the unknown $\mu$ and $\sigma$.

Comment: ahhhh that makes so much sense! thank you very much!